# Why Is it that when I try to scrape the links to the PDFs on this web page I just get an empty list in return?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape the links to the PDFs on this [web page](https://occ.ca/our-publications/). However, I am getting an empty list in return. Any help to this problem would be much appreciated.

Here is the code I used:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv
url="https://occ.ca/our-publications/"
source=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
match=soup.find_all('div')
print(match)
```

Comment: What is the contents of `source`? What's is the status code of the request? Maybe the server is returning some kind of error and not the page you see in your browser.

Comment: HTTP debugging 101: check the http response status code and content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = source = requests.get('https://occ.ca/our-publications/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html')
    pdfs = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "publicationoverlay"})
    links = [pdf.find('a').attrs['href'] for pdf in pdfs]
    print(links)
```

output

```
['https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/The-Great-Mosaic-Reviving-Ontarios-Regional-Economies.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/OCC-Letter-in-support-of-the-OPG-Pickering-Nuclear-Nomination.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/OCC-Beverage-Alcohol-Report.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/Industrial-Electricity-Rates.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/OCC-Letter_Strategic-Approach-to-Alcohol-Sales.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/OCC-Submission-Modernizing-Ontarios-Environmental-Assessment-Program.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/OCC-Letter-on-Ticket-Sales-Act.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018-2019-Policy-Report-Card.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/Letter-on-Right-to-Repair-May-1.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/Federal-Carbon-Tax-Transparency-Act-2019-OCC.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/Waste-and-Litter-Submission-_-Final.pdf', 'https://occ.ca/wp-content/uploads/Supporting-Ontarios-Budding-Cannabis-Industry.pdf']
```

Answer (score 1):

The page is returning a 403 (Forbidden Request) and some error page. If you add an user agent header it returns 200 (OK) with the page you need:

```
requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because in your original request you are getting a 403 forbidden request. 
Python requests by default adds Headers like this:

```
{
 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.21.0', 
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
 'Accept': '*/*', 
 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
 'Content-Length': '40', 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }
```

Some sites blocks such headers. So you're getting a 403 HTTP Error.

```
source=requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'})
```

Adding this will solve that problem and you will get the content you desire.